# Filter x number of lines from output in python

Tags: python

What I have is a small script that will take a server name and a port and check to see if anything is listening on it. Grosh is basically a command like ssh, but it prints out some unnecessary garbage in the first few lines that I wish removed and leave the output of the lsof command.

```
print "Checking " + SRV + ":" + PORT
os.system('grosh %s "lsof -i:%s"' % (unicode(SRV), unicode(PORT)))
```

Comment: If you're doing an `os.system` call, there's likely no way around this. You might be interested in [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) instead

Answer (score 1):

Use `sed` to remove the first 10 lines:

```
n = 10
os.system('grosh %s "lsof -i:%s" | sed "1,%dd"' % (unicode(SRV), unicode(PORT), n))
```